# C#: How to detect arguments typed into console application?

Tags: c#

How would I go upon detecting input for a console application in C#?

Let's say for example I want the console application to start up by writing:
Welcome To Food Hut
(cursor to type stuff here after the first line)

I would want the console application to detect two commands:

1: /help - which will display some help gibberish.

2: /food pizza -t pepperoni -d pepsi - which will display "So you would like a Pizza with Pepperoni and Pepsi to drink?"

How would I go upon detecting first what /command was typed and also reading the arguments like -t pepperoni (topping) and -d pepsi (to drink) if /food pizza was typed?

My main problem is figuring out how to detect the first word ever typed, figuring out that if it was /help then call some method that would post some help text into the console or if the command is /food then to read what is after the /food command, -t, and -p.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Food Hut");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // if readline equals to /help then display some help text.


        // if /food command is typed, read first argument after /food Pizza, -t TheTopping
        // and -p ForWhatToDrink

        // and then display, 'So you would like a Pizza with Pepperoni and Pepsi to drink?'
    }
```

Answer (score 40):

I recommend [Richard Lopes' Command Line Arguments Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx). It is powerful and very simple to use. Also, it accepts various ways of specifying the arguments, for example:

- /name=Stefan
- --name=Stefan
- --name="Multiple words"
- -name 'Stefan'

**Example Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Arguments cmdline = new Arguments(args);

    Console.WriteLine(cmdline["name"]);
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to go! Thanks much to both Richard Lopes and Stefan Schultze.

Comment: Where is the Arguments object coming from? My command line project doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @theJerm This is definitely old and you probably figure this out but for those that might not know...you have to copy the Arguments class into your project from the code project article in Stefan's link before you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

My immediate suggestion would be something like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "/help") { }
else if (input.StartsWith("/food")) { }
else { //... }
```

Barring that, the next simplest solution involves regex. If you need something truly extensible, you might look into a lexer/parser.

But then again, something tells me you're approaching the problem the wrong way. Maybe it would just be easier to display a menu to your user, something like this:

```
Food:
1) Tofu
2) Tempeh
3) Seitan
4) Soup

Choice (1-4)? [users input]

Drink:
1) Pepsi
2) Coffee
3) Water
4) Tea
5) Juice

Choice (1-5)? [users input]
```

Numbered menus might be a little easier for your users to digest.

Answer (score 3):

Use string.split to find all words separated by a space.

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] commands = input.Split(' ');
if(commands[0] == "/food")
{
 if(commands[1] == "Pizza");
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To skip coding basics, you might want to take a look inside [Genghis project](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/Genghis/)'s Command line parsing sub-project by [Chris Sells](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/). It's first one in the table on linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Look into String.Contains

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right, you will need to use the various String members to accomplish this task.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx)

If you are feeling really enterprise, you can look at using the String.Text.RegularExpression class to parse the text, but to start out, use the string members.

Also try googling C# String parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Came across [gsscoder/commandline](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline). A clean Object Oriented implementation, available through NuGet.

Answer (score -3):

What about this case:

```
mssinp.exe -cf "C:\Temp\config.txt"
```

the value for the parameter will be splited as

```
[0] 'C'
[1] '\Temp\config.txt'
```

Comment: please do not post questions/notes as answers