# c# console application arguments

Tags: c#, console

In console applications, when you run exe file (such as ipconfig) you can add parameters, such as /?, or some times its with - . My question is, is there some build in resource or right way to do it or its just on programmers decision and simple regex usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to detect arguments typed into console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316463/c-how-to-detect-arguments-typed-into-console-application)

Comment: Found by typing question title into 'Ask a question'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is completely a programmers decision. It is a good (recommended) way, to do nothing completely new to the user. So, if your program accepts "/" and "-" as well, it will be easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Check the CommandLine Parsing API from ere:

http://testapi.codeplex.com/

I've used  it in any commandline application I've dev.