# How to use arguments in c# console application?

Tags: c#, console, arguments

how can i use arguments in c# console application?
hello everyone
what is arguments?and how to use it in C# Console?
i want,when the user input was empty.
it shows help
also,when the user input was wrong,it shows help too.
help me 
thanks a lot

Comment: Here's a good place to get started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx

Comment: Do you use the search function of SO? If not please refer this [quesiont and it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316463/c-how-to-detect-arguments-typed-into-console-application).

Answer (score 2):

All parameters is in string array called args.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 }
```

Simple program `Name.exe` execute like this:

```
Name.exe param1 param2
```

all params - param1 and param2 is in `string[] args`

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   var param1 = args[0];
   var param2 = args[1];
 }
```

Example of use like You want:

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        if (args.Length == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Help message - no parameters or param1 is empty ");
        }
    }
```

You can use some external dll which help use the parameters I prefer this

GetOpt -  https://getopt.codeplex.com/

**WARN:**

There are some tips to use parameter. When You run program like this:

```
 Name.exe "param1" param2
```

param1 is in quotes, param2 is not but in args is like this

```
   var param1 = args[0];  // value is param1 without quotes
   var param2 = args[1];  //value is param2 without quotes
```

Quotes is for situation when You want use space in the parameters

```
  Name.exe "param1    and..." param2
```

Result is:

```
  var param1 = args[0];  // value is param1    and... without quotes 
  var param2 = args[1];  //value is param2
```